# Regex (HTML/Javascript) - get all digits and full stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to use regex to extract just digits and decimal points in a format that I can then parseFloat to use in equations. I have table cells with a class of "pricePH" and in these cells there's some text along the lines of "£4.50 per head".

The closest I've got is this:

```
/\d\.\d\d/g
```

Which works fine if there is only 3 digits in the price but if there are any more, obviously it'll just extract the last 3 digits. I understand why this doesn't work - I just don't know what I need to do to get the desired result.

How can I extract the entire price? i.e. if the text is "£4.50 per head", the regex will output "4.50", and if the text is "£450.00 per head", it'll output "450.00".

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AThomas92/6Sc48/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regx:

```
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Sc48/1/)**

Comment: Great, thanks Amit! Could you kindly explain what each bit does?

I get that the [0-9] sections are looking for digits, and the \. is looking for the decimal point, but all those modifiers are a mystery to me I'm afraid.

Comment: hi Godge! does this visual help? https://www.debuggex.com/r/V3yDhxUz-_vf8D-R - you can expand the cheatsheet at the bottom of that link to have an explanation of what the modifiers mean

Comment: @amp Yeah that's definitely made things a bit clearer for me, thanks! Another handy tool to bookmark too!

Comment: and actually this one looks neat too and breaks down your expression: http://regex101.com/r/zY4lC7

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question but should provide a great tool for answering the question yourself. There is a tool called Expresso which is free which provides a great way to build and test regular expressions.

http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

This tool has helped me debug regular expressions many times.

Comment: Thanks David, that looks uber-handy! I never even thought to look for such a thing to be honest.